# Is it possible to preserve Light Table (or Album) ordering when exporting from Aperture?

Tags: aperture

I'd like to export my Light Table to disk using a custom counter that preserves the ordering of the Light Table. Alternatively, I'd like to do the same for an Album.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This always works for me as is in Aperture (v 3.1.2).

Are you pressing v to get to the browser view for the specific album or light table before exporting. You can drag things into manual order or specify any other sort like Date, Rating or other sorting. At that point when you export as versions, the counter takes the pictures in the order shown.

Here a pair of clips of Light Tables and the control for ordering.

[image: Select a Light Table]

[image: drag to sort manually or select another option]

Comment: Hmm… [Apparently that option is entiriely disabled in a Light Table?](https://img.skitch.com/20110626-t8k1g66cdkf9yjap9m9a3p3ekr.png)

Comment: Not at all - I'm showing you manual exists in all of my Light Tables. Perhaps you need to rerrange at least one thumbnail for manual to exist. (perhaps there isn't a manual ordering until you make one by reordering one of the others)

Comment: Ah. I see where the confusion was. I can indeed enable manual ordering in the grid and filmstrip views, but they are not in the order that I put the photos _on_ the light table. What I was hoping for is something that honored the ordering of the light table. At the same time, your tip is pretty useful in that I can at least take the photos I rearranged on the light table and use them as reference to the manual reordering of the photos in the filmstrip. Maybe update your answer to show that it's completely not possible and then I can accept it. Thanks for all your help!